# What is a open source data store for bare metal Cortex M3 without OS

Tags: c, datastore

I am looking for suggestions for a data store written in C that will compile for ARM Cortex M3 without any operating system.

I want it to be:

- written in C
- preferably free and/or open source
- able to be compiled with GCC
- works on bare metal processor without operating system or file system support

It can be SQL or not.  I would like something like MongoDB that is compatible with with JSON (i.e. can serialize via JSON in plain C char buffers.)

The needs of the datastore would be to manage data in RAM from a fixed allocation of memory.  No "dynamic" allocation (i.e. no malloc).

Comment: I'm currently reviewing sqlite3 to see if it meets my requirements above.

Comment: I'm also reviewing Berkeley DB.  However, links to compiling this or sqlite3 for bare metal ARM Cortex M3 would be helpful.

Comment: sqlite and bdb requires OS services such as memory allocation file, i/o and many other things, you'll have a really hard time porting those (or any other open source data store) to run bare metal.

Comment: @nos, this is what I am finding.  What I'd like is a simple key-value store that manages the memory chunks.  It would be nice if I could serialize the entire database (or chunks), so I could move it to and from non-volatile storage, but I'd like it operate out of RAM.  I realize there are simpler ways to do this, but I would like to have a generic way to store "records" for certain data that the end user will control.

Comment: @nos, maybe a simple in-RAM hash is what I'm looking for instead? (very much like JSON)  Any suggestions about this are also welcome.  I have started this search many times before and always reached dead ends.

Comment: I am also looking at yajl for this.

Comment: Hey, just wondering if you ever figured out something for this?

Comment: @zhyfer, no I didn't find a good solution for my needs.  I started writing one here: https://github.com/jpmec/tbd  However, it is still a toy and not very efficient.

Comment: @zhyfer, the biggest hurdle was no file system support and not using malloc.

Answer (score 3):

SQLite3 is a very good contender, but if you a just looking for a small and simple key/value store the you should also look up [gdbm](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/).

Comment: I was able to download and configure on Mac, although cross compiling gdbm for ARM looks some what challenging.  I gave a +1 for the suggestion.  I'm going to wait for other answers before I select one.