# How to compute offset between two different struct members in C?

Tags: c, struct

Consider the following C code:

```
struct Foo
{
  short a;
  long b;
  char c;
  void* d;
};
```

I know it is possible to know the size of the entire structure using sizeof.  Is it possible to know the size of a subset of this structure, or (stated differently) know the distance between two members?  I realize could nest structures based on the offsets I want (then it is possible to use sizeof), but say I wanted to know the number of bytes between a and d?  Also, I'd like to do this without instantiating an object (something like sizeof).  (I realize if I have a object, then I could look at the address differences between foo.d and foo.a).  Is this possible?

Comment: The correct term is "members", not "attributes". Incidentally, I can't think of a good use for this information; what do you intend to do with it? Is it possible that you have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/167210)?

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes it is possible I have an XY problem.  I will think more about this, given there is an answer to my original question.  It is possible I didn't need offsetof.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
offsetof(Foo, d) - offsetof(Foo, a)
```

`offsetof` gives you the offset from the beginning of `Foo` to the member specified.

You'll need `#include <stddef.h>`

Comment: For what it's worth, `offsetof` is a pretty smelly macro and often indicative that you are doing something nefarious.

Comment: @DavidG yes, I was actually going to use this for some black magic voodoo full of void* casting and such (I'm not kidding).  Your sense of smell is impeccable :-)

Comment: @David G: Quite the opposite. "Something nefarious" would be trying to implement `offsetof` manually (as people often do for some unexplainable reason). The concept of "member offset" is so useful, that in C++ it was even generalized and turned into a core language feature - pointers of pointer-to-member type. In C we just have `offsetof` for that purpose. There's nothing nefarious in it (by C standards) as long as the standard macro is used.

Comment: @DavidG offsetof is indispensable when writing "containerof" macros which are necessary for implementing lists in C where the node is embedded in the struct

Comment: @Ancurio, your description is sort of what I am trying to do.  I am trying to implement a generic container where the user give a chunk of memory, and I subdivide it.  The bookkeeping information is kept inside the same chunk of memory as the data (much like your example).  I don't know enough yet to know if I have an XY problem, or if I even need offsetof.  It is amazing that you all know so much about my problem (I feel that I am not so much standing on the shoulders of giants, as walking miles behind them in their footsteps.)

Comment: BTW, what caused this question was trying to write some prototype code for this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604902/what-is-a-open-source-data-store-for-bare-metal-cortex-m3-without-os